# pipe stdout and prepend some chars for each line

Tags: bash

I want to pipe the stdout of a process through a "tool" to prepend some chars to each line. I'm working in a bash.

Example:

```
PREPEND=' * '
foo.bin | toolXY "$PREPEND"
```

If foo.bin will output:

```
hello
world
```

the Output after toolXY should be:

```
 * hello
 * world
```

What whould be the command for `toolXY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo.bin | sed "s/^/$PREPEND/"
```

or

```
foo.bin | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$PREPEND $line"; done
```

The second is more robust if `$PREPEND` can contain unpredictable special characters. `IFS=` preserves leading whitespace on each line and `-r` protects backslashes from being interpreted as escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Awk would work for this as well.

```
cat foo.bin | awk 'PREPEND=" * " {print PREPEND $0}'
```

Comment: If `$PREPEND` is an existing shell variable, use `awk -vPREPEND="$PREPEND" '{print PREPEND $0}'`.